# Update 2 fields depending on each other value but each one depends also on other properties values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have 2 text fields that represent `Xmin` and `Xmax` values of a quadrangle, this values are initialized on constructor of `myClass`.

Also I have 2 more fields, `Delta` and `Counter`, that depending on `Xmin` and `Xmax` they must be updated using formulas:

```
this.Delta = (int)((this.Xmax - this.Xmin) / (this.Counter - 1));
```

and

```
this.Counter = ((this.Xmax - this.Xmin) / (this.Delta)) + 1 ;
```

This seems not so difficult, However I would like to allow `Delta` and `Counter` to be updated if other changes, i.e. if `Delta` changes then `Counter` updates and viceversa, all of this
considering `Xmin` and `Xmax` values

here is what I have

## wpf

```
<GroupBox Header="Values" Height="93" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,3,0,0" Name="GBoxGridDefinition" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="624">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="20"  Margin="20,13,0,0" Name="TbXmin" Text="Xmin:"  Width="36" />                        
    <controls:WaterMarkNumericInput x:Name="TBXmin" Height="20" Width="89"   Margin="59,9,0,0" Style="{StaticResource goStRWMNI}" Number="{Binding Path=Xmin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" IsNullAllowed="False" />
    <TextBlock Height="20"  Margin="154,10,0,0" Name="TbXmax" Text="Xmax:"  Width="36" />                        
    <controls:WaterMarkNumericInput x:Name="TBXmax" Height="20" Width="89"   Margin="198,10,0,0" Style="{StaticResource goStRWMNI}" Number="{Binding Path=Xmax, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" IsNullAllowed="False" />
</Grid>
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Header="Dynamic changes" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,98,0,0" Name="GbxNodes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="463" >
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="20"  Margin="28,7,0,0" Name="TbDelta" Text="Delta X:"  Width="48" />                        
    <controls:WaterMarkNumericInput x:Name="TBDelta" Height="20" Width="119"   IsNegativeSignAllowed="False" Margin="90,4,0,0" Style="{StaticResource goStRWMNI}" Number="{Binding Path=Delta, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" IsNullAllowed="False"/>
    <TextBlock Height="20"  Margin="223,6,0,0" Name="TbCounter" Text="XX' nodes counter:"  Width="109" />
    <controls:WaterMarkNumericInput x:Name="TBCounter" IsEnabled="False" Height="20" Width="111"   Margin="330,4,0,0" Style="{StaticResource goStRWMNI}" Number="{Binding Path=Counter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" IsNullAllowed="False" />
</Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

I have added binding and property change, At the beginning `Counter = 100`, but I do not know how to update `Counter` when `Delta` changed and viceversa

Here is c# code

```
public partial class myClass : UserControl
{
    double gnXmin, gnXmax, gnCounter;
    int gnDelta;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public double Xmin
    {
        get { return gnXmin; }
        set { gnXmin = value;  OnPropertyChanged("Xmin"); }
    }
    public double Xmax
    {
        get { return gnXmax; }
        set { gnXmax = value; OnPropertyChanged("Xmax");  }
    }
    public int Delta
    {
        get { return gnDelta; }
        set { gnDelta = value; OnPropertyChanged("Delta"); }
    }
    public double Counter
    {
        get { return gnCounter; }
        set { gnCounter = value; OnPropertyChanged("Counter"); }
    }
    public myClass(double _Xmin, double _Xmax)
    {
        this.Xmin  = _Xmin;
        this.Xmax = _Xmax;
        this.Counter  = 100;
        this.Delta = (int)((this.Xmax - this.Xmin) / (this.Counter - 1));
    }
    void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    
}
```

How can I update both elements or bind them so each one is modified when other is modified, but considering `Xmin` and `Xmax` properties?

I tried putting update code inside getter and setter but as one field depends on `Xmin` and `Xmax` I get an infinite loop exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the infinite loop, make sure that the passed `value` really is different from the current value in the setter, before doing anything else:

```
public double Counter
{ 
    get { ... }
    set 
    {
        if (gnCounter != value)
        {  
            gnCounter = value;
            Delta = (int)((Xmax - Xmin) / (gnCounter  - 1));
            OnPropertyChanged("Counter");
        } 
    }
}
```

And of course, you have to do the same for the `Delta` property.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for this question "how to update Counter when Delta changed and viceversa??"
Notify Counter when Delta value is changed and notify Delta when counter is changed. If this solution doesnt help then let me know

```
public int Delta
    {
        get { return gnDelta; }
        set { gnDelta = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("Delta"); 
              OnPropertyChanged("Counter");}
    }
    public double Counter
    {
        get { return gnCounter; }
        set { gnCounter = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Counter");
            OnPropertyChanged("Delta"); }
    }
```